# Find the average GDP of multiple countries at once

Tags: curated-data, geography, wolfram-alpha-queries

How would I find the average GDP of a list of countries between set years?

I know how to do it for one but I'm not sure about multiple values. I also wish to find the average population size.

An example of what I want: a list of the average GDPs of each individual country France, Germany, Spain, Russia, Portugal and Poland between the years 1999 and 2008.

How would I do the same for population?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue). The countries:

```
countries = Map[
    Entity["Country",#]&,
    {"France","Germany","Spain","Russia","Portugal","Poland"}
];
```

Using [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue):

```
interval = Interval[{DateObject[{1999}], DateObject[{2008}]}];

dataset = EntityValue[
    countries,
    {
    EntityProperty["Country","GDP",{"Date"->interval}],
    EntityProperty["Country","Population",{"Date"->interval}]
    },
    "Dataset"
];
```

The dataset contains the information you want, although the values are encoded in [`TimeSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries)/[`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData) objects. For instance:

```
ts = dataset[[1,1]];
Head @ ts
```

> TemporalData

To extract values from a [`TimeSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries)/[`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData) object you give it the date you are interested in:

```
ts[DateObject[{2004}]]
```

> Quantity[2.12411*10^12, ("USDollars")/("Years"), {}]

So, to obtain the population of Russia in 2004:

```
dataset[Entity["Country", "Russia"], 2, #[DateObject[{2004}]]&]
```

> Quantity[144306982, "People", {}]

Or, the average GDP for all of the countries for the year 2002:

```
dataset[Mean, 1, #[DateObject[{2002}]]&]
```

> Quantity[8.27107*10^11, ("USDollars")/("Years")]

Plot of the average GDP from 1999 to 2008:

```
dataset[DateListPlot @* Mean, 1]
```

[image]

Plot of the GDP for each country from 1999 to 2008:

```
dataset[DateListPlot,1]
```

[image]

Distribution of population in the year 2003:

```
PieChart[
    dataset[All, 2, #[DateObject[{2003}]]&],
    ChartLabels->Callout[Automatic]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways:

```
CountryData["Sweden", {"GDP", {1999, 2008}}] // Mean
```

and

```
ts = Entity["Country", "Sweden"][
   EntityProperty["Country", "GDP", {
     "CurrencyUnit" -> "CurrentUSDollar",
     "Date" -> All
     }]
   ];
TimeSeriesWindow[ts, {{1999, 1, 1}, {2008, 1, 1}}] // Mean
```

[We can use free-form input](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153130/731) to get the entities. Search for "historic GDP Sweden", to get the entities used in the snippet here above.

To do this for the population, we would proceed in the same way. To do it for other countries, we would simply need to replace "Sweden" in the above code. Example:

```
Mean@CountryData[#, {"GDP", {1999, 2008}}] & /@ {"France", "Germany", "Spain"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @hellohi All data is not exposed through `CountryData`. For these cases, switch to using the entity approach. Start by finding the international migrant stock entity property by using free form input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way.

```
countries = {"France", "Germany", "Spain", "Russia", "Portugal", "Poland"};
yearMin = 1999; yearMax = 2008;

With[{property = "GDP"}, 
     ds = AssociationThread[Range[yearMin, yearMax] -> (Association /@
                     Table[country -> CountryData[country, {property, year}],
                           {year, yearMin, yearMax}, {country, countries}])] // Dataset]
```

[image: dataset]

and then

```
ds[Mean, All] // Normal // QuantityMagnitude
   <|"France" -> 1.983877562406246*^12, "Germany" -> 2.656085060866531*^12, 
     "Spain" -> 1.0072285825063357*^12, "Russia" -> 6.843191640802267*^11, 
     "Portugal" -> 1.763798635199338*^11, "Poland" -> 2.806974107570857*^11|>
```

If you want just the means themselves:

```
Mean /@ Association[Table[country -> CountryData[country, {"GDP", {yearMin, yearMax}}],
                          {country, countries}]] // QuantityMagnitude
```